# display image of unknown size in jsp

Tags: html, css, image, jsp

I have a web app in which I let users to upload their logo image. This image has no restrictions about width and height. Then in a JSP I display the logo for each user. The problem is each user's logo has different dimensions (small, big...)
which would be the best way to display the image??

Comment: How you are displaying the image in jsp page? If you are using image attribute set width and height for that attribute. It will display as you mentioned regardless of size and it's dimension.

Comment: A priori I dont know image's width and height, as users can upload whatever they want

Comment: I assume that each image will be limited in size when displayed regardless of it's size when uploaded?

Comment: That may not be issue. U can set width and height by yourself though it is small.

Comment: yes, but I don't want images to get distorted. The only thing you can assume is I'm going to display the image in a div 300x215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all images are going to be constrained then apply a width to the parent and add a max-width to the image.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2pH48/)

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-5.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

.img {
    width:250px;
}

.img img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I haven't said that all images are going to be constrained, for example an user can upload a logo of 50x50

Comment: thanks Paulie_D but how could I center the image in case its width is less than 250px ?

Comment: It should just display normally. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2pH48/1/

Comment: Eh Paulie! as you can see in your own example the 50x50 image is aligned to the left, I would prefer center-align. Is this possible??

Comment: Sure just use `margin:0 auto` on the image. NB. You may have to tell the image to `display:block`. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/2pH48/2/